# how to create a light map in unity5?

Tags: unity-game-engine, lighting

Hi I have created a scene in unity where lighting is pretty important but the more I use , the performance goes down.So I want to use light mapping,which i assume is something where i wont actually have any light component in the hierarchy but there is illumination.How do I create a light map ? Can anybody help me with that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Window > Lightmapping,
2. Select all assets you need.
3. Right Uppercorner > Static > Lightmap static
4. Bake > Mode > Single Lightmaps
5. Bake Scene

And the most important thing...

6. Enjoy